# hovering listener is not working the way how focusing listener will, why?

Tags: android, android-framework

I have a two views in my layout.

**View1 and view2.**

action : Moving from View1 to view2 using 1.dpad (focuslistener).2.pointer(hoverlistener).

**In case of Focus listener :**

first it is sending the **false event to View1.**
second it is sending the **true event to View2**.

**In case of Hover listener :**

first it is sending the **true event to View2.**
second it is sending the **false event to View1**.

why this order of hovering events are handled differently compare to focusing events?
please provide the sufficient information.